# How to create an object in a one to many relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have parents and children. As you'd expect, a Parent 'hasMany' Child objects. I am able to create a new Parent just fine, but I can not get new Child objects to show up on my template. According to the Chrome and Firefox Ember debug tool, it looks like the Child objects are being created in the store correctly. But the new children never appear in the template.

I believe I've followed the Ember [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/) to the letter, and yet I can not get my code to work.

I've created the following jsbin to demonstrate my situation. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zodorule

How do I create new many-related objects in Ember?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Data isn't a database, so setting the relationship from one side won't automatically hook it up from the other.

```
  var child = this.store.createRecord('Child', {name: 'Fred'});
  this.store.find('parent', 1).then(function(parent) {
    child.set('parent', parent);
    parent.get('children').then(function(children){
      children.pushObject(child);
    });
  });
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/xorov/1/edit

Comment: ahh that makes sense. Is there some resource besides the official that explains these things? Or what should I have known from reading the docs?

Comment: Hah, no, the documentation is close to non-existent on relationships (due it it still being in beta).  This doc used to be really helpful, but pointless in this situation https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md